# sendReliableRealTimeMessage is not giving any callback

Tags: google-play-games

Here i'm using following code for sending message. I added the callback listener to know message status but its not printing any log message.

```
gamesClient.sendReliableRealTimeMessage(new RealTimeReliableMessageSentListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRealTimeMessageSent(int statusCode, int tokenId, String recipientParticipantId) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                switch (statusCode) {
                case GamesClient.STATUS_OK:
                    Log.e("status", "STATUS_OK");
                    break;
                case GamesClient.STATUS_REAL_TIME_MESSAGE_SEND_FAILED:
                    Log.e("status", "STATUS_REAL_TIME_MESSAGE_SEND_FAILED");
                    break;
                case GamesClient.STATUS_REAL_TIME_ROOM_NOT_JOINED:
                    Log.e("status", "STATUS_REAL_TIME_ROOM_NOT_JOINED");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }, msgBuf, roomId, p.getParticipantId());
```

Comment: Although I've had my share of dropped messages.. it isn't the normal case for sendReliableRealTimeMessage().  2 things.. are you receiving any messages on your other device? (whether reliable or unreliably sent)   Are you able to post how you've setup your Activity (declarations etc..)

Comment: I'm not receiving the message in another device.

Comment: Hey I got solution. I updated my libraries now its working fine

Answer (score 3):

Don't use anonymous listeners like that. The API uses weak references to listeners, so it often happens that these listeners will get garbage-collected before they are called. Please try again using a non-anonymous listener, that is, a listener that you hold a reference to. One easy way to do that is make the Activity the listener (i.e. add "implements RealTimeReliableMessageSentListener" to the Activity class).

Another option is to hold an explicit reference to the listener as a member variable in your Activity.